# Can't check in due to conflicting changes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I have an issue that means I cannot check in changes even if I resolve the issues.

I have removed a form from the solution then created a new form with the same name.  Now when I go to check in the form I get the following error:
http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/144/errorm.png

Even if I mark all the conflicts as resolved the check in fails with the following error: All conflicts resolved but no files checked in due to initial conflicts.

How can I get this to check in?

Comment: What kind of change are you making: edit or add?

Comment: I removed the old files and added the new ones with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the source explorer and delete the files directly in there.

Comment: When I try delete the old files I get an error about pending changes, but if I try undo the changes then I get this error:
TF14059: Unable to process the pending changes requested. The set of pending renames would cause a name collision for $/Bespoke/Religion/dhc.Scanning/dhc.Scanning/GUI/GoodsOutwards.vb.

Comment: This worked but I had to remove the new files first then undo the changes on the old files before I could remove them from source control.

Comment: I had the same problem and the only way I was able to fix it was to copy my changed files somewhere else, revert my files back to the ones in the source control and then copy my changed files back over the restored old files. Then I was able to check the files into TFS.